# Query optimization in base64 conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, base64

I'm encrypting an `image` column by converting the data into `base64`. But now I'm doing the conversion and saving the data in another column from there I encrypt.

I actually don't want the additional column and store the `base64` converted value.

//Table

```
create table dbo.tblImageTest (img Image, encimg varbinary(MAX), base64img VARCHAR(MAX))
```

//This part I wanted it to be on the fly. This is an existing table in which I have to process for all the records - just an FYI for the subquery

```
UPDATE dbo.tblImageTest   
SET base64img = ( 
select 
    
    base64_img1 = CAST('' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("img1"))','VARCHAR(MAX)')
from (
    select 
         
        img1 = cast(img as varbinary(MAX))
    from dbo.tblImageTest 
    ) T
```

// This update can handle both the conversion and encryption

```
UPDATE dbo.tblImageTest   
SET encimg  
    = EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('New_Key'), CAST('' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("base64img"))','VARCHAR(MAX)'))
GO
```

So my final table structure will be,

```
create table dbo.tblImageTest (img Image, encimg varbinary(MAX))
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: The `text`, `ntext`, and `image` data types have been deprecated since SQL Server 2005 and should not be used in new development. Use the `varchar(max)`, `nvarchar(max)` and `varbinary(max)` data types instead. Ref: [ntext, text, and image (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql)

Comment: Why would you encrypt the base64, why not just encrypt the bare `varbinary` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what's the actual problem you're having, just put it all together?

```sql
UPDATE t
SET encimg  = EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('New_Key'), CAST('' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("img1"))','VARCHAR(MAX)'))
from dbo.tblImageTest t
cross apply (
    SELECT  cast(img as varbinary(MAX)) AS img1
    ) x
```